# Saving GridView after onDestroy

Tags: android, gridview, onpause, ondestroy

How can I save a GridView with Vector list in android? I 'm developing a launcher and I want the shortcuts to be saved after onDestroy or any crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly mean, but why not save data using SharedPreferences
at some stage while the application is running? or when user makes some changes.

Here is an example of how to use sharedpreferences.
[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3624280/1630780)

you can also check other storage options available here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I want to save the grid view after the items where added. Should I use SharedPreferences?

Comment: Depends on how big is your data and type of data. if your data is small then use SharedPreferences otherwise check out other storage options.